# Hierarchy tree sort by alphabet

Tags: php, arrays, tree, hierarchy, alphabetical

The current code works very well. But is it possible to put the first letter of the main array above the word? And do not repeat as in the word "More" below. As an example below. G, M, W... and others if they have.
Thanks for the help. I do not know if I explained it correctly.

```
G
Good

M 
Men
  ╚═►Watches
     ╚═►Rolex

More

W 
Women
  ╚═►Bras
     ╚═►Bedroom  
  ╚═►Jackets
```

Using the code php below.

```
    /**
 * Heres your categories array structure, they can be in any order as we will sort them into an hierarchical structure in a moment
 */
$categories = array();
$categories[] = array('id'=>9, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name' => 'More', 'slug' => 'more', 'status' => 1);
$categories[] = array('id'=>8, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Good', 'slug' => 'good', 'status' => 1);
$categories[] = array('id'=>5, 'parent_id' => 4, 'name' => 'Bedroom wear', 'slug' => 'bwear', 'status' => 1);
$categories[] = array('id'=>6, 'parent_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Rolex', 'slug' => 'rolex', 'status' => 1);
$categories[] = array('id'=>1, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Men', 'slug' => 'men', 'status' => 1);
$categories[] = array('id'=>2, 'parent_id' => 0, 'name' => 'Women', 'slug' => 'women', 'status' => 1);
$categories[] = array('id'=>3, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Watches', 'slug' => 'watches', 'status' => 1);
$categories[] = array('id'=>4, 'parent_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Bras', 'slug' => 'bras', 'status' => 1);
$categories[] = array('id'=>7, 'parent_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Jackets', 'slug' => 'jackets', 'status' => 1);


/**
 * This function takes the categories and processes them into a nice tree like array
 */
function preprocess_categories($categories) {

    // First of all we sort the categories array by parent id!
    // We need the parent to be created before teh children after all?
    $parent_ids = array();
    foreach($categories as $k => $cat) {
        $parent_ids[$k] = $cat['parent_id'];
        $main_nm[$k] = $cat['name'];
    }
    //array_multisort($parent_ids, SORT_ASC, $categories);
    array_multisort($parent_ids, SORT_ASC, $main_nm, SORT_ASC, $categories);

    /* note: at this point, the categories are now sorted by the parent_id key */

    // $new contains the new categories array which you will pass into the tree function below (nothign fancy here)
    $new = array();

    // $refs contain references (aka points) to places in the $new array, this is where the magic happens!
    // without references, it would be difficult to have a completely random mess of categories and process them cleanly
    // but WITH references, we get simple access to children of children of chilren at any point of the loop
    // each key in this array is teh category id, and the value is the "children" array of that category
    // we set up a default reference for top level categories (parent id = 0) 
    $refs = array(0=>&$new);

    // Loop teh categories (easy peasy)
    foreach($categories as $c) {

        // We need the children array so we can make a pointer too it, should any children categories popup
        $c['children'] = array();

        // Create the new entry in the $new array, using the pointer from $ref (remember, it may be 10 levels down, not a top level category) hence we need to use the reference/pointer
        $refs[$c['parent_id']][$c['id']] = $c;

        // Create a new reference record for this category id
        $refs[$c['id']] = &$refs[$c['parent_id']][$c['id']]['children'];

    }

    return $new;

}

/**
 * This function generates our HTML from the categories array we have pre-processed
 */
function tree($categories, $baseurl = '/category/') {

     $tree = "<ul>";

     foreach($categories as $category) {

        $tree .= "<li>";

        $tree .= "<a href='".$baseurl.$category['slug']."'>".$category['name']."</a>";

        // This is the magci bit, if there are children categories, the function loops back on itself
        // and processes the children as if they were top level categories
        // we append the children to the main tree string rather tha echoing for this reason
        // we also pass the base url PLUS our category slug as the "new base url" so it can build the URL correctly
        if(!empty($category['children'])) {

            $tree .= tree($category['children'], $baseurl.$category['slug'].'/');

        }

        $tree .= "</li>";


     }

     $tree .= "</ul>";

     return $tree;

}

///echo "<pre>"; print_r(preprocess_categories($categories)); die();
echo tree( preprocess_categories( $categories ) );
```

Comment: The tree function creates an HTML list with categories. Is it in this function, that you would like to complete with G, M, W?

Comment: Yes, but without repeating. The first letter of the main array (not the child) and insert together in the list in alphabetical order. Same as the example I made up there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to handle this is looping through the `$new` array one more time. I put together a quick edit to your code, below. Put this in the `preprocess_categories` function right at the end. Remember to remove your `return $new;` line of the code. The code snippet attached has the `return` already in there.

```
    // SET A NEW DEFAULT ARRAY

    $new_by_alpha = array();

    // LOOP THROUGH THE $new ARRAY ONE MORE TIME
    // we only need to loop through the top level arrays in the main array since we will keep the children arrays intact

    foreach ( $new as $obj ) {

        // CALCULATE THE MAIN CATS FIRST CHARACTER FROM NAME

        $name   = $obj[ 'name' ];
        $alpha  = strtoupper( substr( $name , 0 , 1 ) );

        // CHECK TO SEE IF THE NEW TOP LEVEL ALPHA ID IS SET IN THE $new_by_alpha ARRAY
        // if its not set, then we create it with default variables and values

        if ( !isset( $new_by_alpha[ $alpha ] ) || empty( $new_by_alpha[ $alpha ] ) ) {

            $new_by_alpha[ $alpha ] = array(

                'id'        => $alpha,
                'name'      => $alpha,
                'slug'      => '#',
                'status'    => 1,
                'chlidren'  => array(),

            );

        }

        // NOW THAT WE ARE SURE THAT THE VERY TOP LEVEL IS SET WE CAN ADD THE FULL OBJECT TO IT

        $new_by_alpha[ $alpha ][ 'children' ][] = $obj;

    }

    return $new_by_alpha;
```

Essentially what's happening here, is we're taking the top level arrays within your `$new` array, and just reorganizing them within new top level arrays.

Comment: Did this help you, Eder? Or is there anything I clarify?